# Enable FIPS mode on CISCO Router

Tags: cisco

Can someone please tell me how to enable/disable FIPS mode on CISCO Router?

Comment: Which Cisco router? What IOS version? There are so many to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://www.cisco.com/web/strategy/government/security_certification/net_business_benefit_seccert_fips140.html), it seems that a lot of routers can be FIPS-compliant.

It may require a special IOS version, and [tamper evidence labels](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_modules/fips/non-opacity_shield_cover_letter/fipsflyr.html) (to install on chassis, memory and interface cards).